# Update SQL query is deadlocking itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have re-created my query:

```
MERGE [Unshipped] u
USING [Order] order or ON or.ID = u.ID

WHEN MATCHED AND u.Date <> or.Date
   THEN
      UPDATE 
      SET u.Date = or.Date

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN 
       INSERT (ID, FK, Date)
       VALUES (or.ID, or.FK, or.Date)
```

Table2

In my real life example this appears to be dead locking itself. There is a clustered index on the ID column.

My research has bought me to two issues:

1. The MATCH part of the MERGE checks the index for matches, read-locking those rows/pages as it goes.
2. When it has a row without a match, it will try to insert the new Index Row first so it will request a row/page write-lock ...

Is this the case for this query? Can anyone advise me any further? What is the best approach to stop this from deadlocking? Any info would be great.

Comment: Try running with option (maxdop 1)

Comment: @user1443098 to run the query on a single core?

Comment: yes, sometimes multi-core operations can cause deadlocks.  If maxdop 1 cures it, good!

Comment: @user1443098 ok great i will have a look! Is there anything else i can try too? thanks

Comment: I am going to assume that you read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/merge-statement-deadlocking-itself since you quote one of the answers as the two issues your research has brought you to. Did you try the suggestions RBarryYoung proposed in that post? 
Also, if you really can't have deadlocks in this MERGE, you could always refactor it into separate INSERT and UPDATE queries.

Comment: What is the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT setting on your database? If false and it is possible to change it, that may solve the issue.